# Sync Twitter tweets to my Facebook wall, but all in a single FB thread

Tags: facebook, twitter

I want to set it up so that all tweets from a single day get posted as replies to a single FB wall thread. So the first tweet of the day would start a new FB wall post, then all other tweets that day would be replies to that post.

The goal is to keep my FB wall from being polluted with lots of small updates, thus not annoy my friends, but still notify friends who Like or Reply to the FB post.

Is there an app that could do this? Or could I easily build something using the Twitter and Facebook APIs (I'm a web developer, it's in my skill set, just not interested in reinventing the wheel).

Comment: Most chances are, you have to make it yourself. Too localized.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up just creating a separate facebook page, and syncing twitter to that. If my friends are interested in my tweets, they can like that page.

Comment: Why not do it in a tab app?

Comment: What do you mean by a tab app?

Comment: http://www.facebook.com/cocacola - Do you see the "Photos" "Likes" "Home" "Your Stories" part? Those are tab apps. You can do what you want on your own server and put it on your Facebook page as a tab app.

Facebook's guide for getting started with tab apps: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/appsonfacebook/pagetabs/